# Command-Right_Arrow and Command-Left_Arrow stopped working in Textmate on OS X Lion 10.7.2

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, osx-lion, textmate

As the title says, I have no clue what has happened, but it's annoying without it.

Anyone had this issue and/or know how to fix it?

Comment: Does it only not work in TextMate, or also e.g. TextEdit? Does it happen for all source code languages? Does it happen for a newly created user account on the same machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/32150/12835) fixed it for me.

> 1. Swipe 4 fingers up to show Mission Control
> 2. Select a full-screen app in the list of desktops
> 3. Swipe 4 fingers up to show Mission Control again
> 4. Select a text editor app on the main Desktop

Comment: What the...! I thought you were messing with us, but those steps really did work!